# Is there a List of Canon EF Push/Pull zoom lenses?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-design

Is there a list of all push/pull zooms that Canon has manufactured for the EF mount?

**I do know the following ones:**
EF 100-400mm f/4.5-5.6 L IS USM
EF 28-300mm f/3.5-5.6 L IS USM
EF 35-350mm f/3.5-5.6 L USM
EF 100-300mm f/5.6
EF 100-300mm f/5.6 L
EF 70-210mm f/4
EF 70-210mm f/3.5-4.5 USM
EF 35-105mm f/3.5-4.5
EF 50-200mm f/3.5-4.5
EF 50-200mm f/3.5-4.5 L

Comment: If there are any Canon would know.  Consider emailing Canon.

Comment: Well there are a few I know of. Like the EF 100-400mm f/4.5-5.6 L IS USM that I got. But I guess most of them are no longer or even none of them so I guess Canon would probably not provide a list for past products.

Comment: They definitely won't if you don't ask them to.

Comment: This is probably true for all questions on this page, some manufacturer/professional might be able to answer all of these if you ask them, the question is why should they and why does this page exist then? The Canon support however was not willing to help with information on any camera bodies out of production last time I asked them so I guess it will be the same for lenses wouldn't it?

Comment: You could have emailed them in the time it took to make that response.

Comment: Actually I did, just to be safe, but I guess that nothing will come back or a sorry we can't help you with that like last time.

Comment: @bardiir What photographic problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @MichaelClark I like zooming with a push/pull style lens much more than the twist ones and I would like to get a shorter one too. Currently I only got the 100-400mm with the push/pull technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Canon Camera Museum](http://global.canon/en/c-museum/index.html):

It looks like you've missed the **EF35-135mm f/3.5-4.5** off your list.

You can look for the rest there too. I've spent only a few minutes to verify your list.

Edit: I shouldn't be lazy.

[EF50-200mm f/3.5-4.5L](http://global.canon/en/c-museum/product/ef275.html)

[EF50-200mm f/3.5-4.5](http://global.canon/en/c-museum/product/ef272.html)

[EF100-300mm f/5.6L](http://global.canon/en/c-museum/product/ef266.html)

[EF100-300mm f/5.6](http://global.canon/en/c-museum/product/ef262.html)

[EF70-210mm f/4](http://global.canon/en/c-museum/product/ef265.html)

[EF35-350mm f/3.5-5.6L USM](http://global.canon/en/c-museum/product/ef315.html)

[EF100-400mm f/4.5-5.6L IS USM](http://global.canon/en/c-museum/product/ef345.html)

[EF28-300mm f/3.5-5.6L IS USM](http://global.canon/en/c-museum/product/ef377.html)

[EF35-105mm f/3.5-4.5](http://global.canon/en/c-museum/product/ef260.html)

[EF35-135mm f/3.5-4.5](http://global.canon/en/c-museum/product/ef274.html)

As far as I can tell, [EF70-210mm f/3.5-4.5 USM](http://global.canon/en/c-museum/product/ef291.html) is NOT push-pull zoom.

Comment: It's a fun place to visit, all sorts of weird lenses. For example, the EF100-200mm f/4.5A, autofocus only lens.